# how to add class active in menu laravel if use treeview

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6

I am having trouble to adding class "menu-open" and "active" if I use a Multi-level menu.

I succeeded in adding active class in single menu.

Single Menu

```
<li class="nav-item">
      <a href="{{ route('listTemuan') }}" class="nav-link {{ Route::currentRouteNamed('listTemuan') ? 'active' : '' }}">
        <i class="fa fa-table nav-icon"></i>
        <p>
          List Temuan
        </p>
      </a>
    </li>
```

I don't understand how to make it in Multi-level menu.

This is for my Multi-level menu:

```
<li class="nav-item has-treeview"> //I want to add class menu-open in here
      <a href="#" class="nav-link"> //I want to add class active in here
        <i class="fa fa-gear nav-icon"></i>
        <p>
          Setting
          <i class="right fa fa-angle-left"></i>
        </p>
      </a>
      <ul class="nav nav-treeview">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="{{ route('UserPekerja') }}" class="nav-link {{ Route::currentRouteNamed('UserPekerja') ? 'active' : '' }}">
            <i class="fa fa-circle-o nav-icon"></i>
            <p>User Pekerja</p>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use your route name to accomplish it like below code

```
@if(\Request::route()->getName() == 'route name')
      class="nav-item has-treeview open"
@else class="nav-item has-treeview"
@endif
```

use same segment with appropriate checking

```
@if(\Request::route()->getName() == 'expected route name')
              class="nav-link active"
@else class="nav-link"
@endif
```

Comment: how if I have multi-level menu more than one, maybe 3 or 4 multi-level menu, so if I use 'if else' statment it will make many code right

Comment: yes, but without checking it, how will you decide about this class?

Comment: in that case, prepare a helper for it & call it for each level. This is the only alternative you can use for it.